# Python stops creating new files during loop

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to Python so I could use some help. I'm basically building a small web scraper for my own personal needs, everything has been going fine up until I want to write the scraped data to a file of its own. Given a list of eighty urls, the loop will stop creating new files but still continue to gather data. I've tested the loop by funnelling all the data into a single file and this works perfectly but I really need separate files to be created. The loop will create 38 separate files instead of the eighty I need. Can anyone help me figure out why? My code is below:

```
while i < len(urls_to_scrape):

    with urllib.request.urlopen(urls_to_scrape[i]) as response:
        html = response.read()

    smashsoup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    title = smashsoup.find('h1').get_text()
    author = smashsoup.find('a', {'itemprop':'author'}).get_text();
    complete_title = title +' By '+ author

    filename = hashlib.md5(complete_title.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() + ".txt"
    imgname = hashlib.md5(complete_title.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() + ".jpg"
    short_desc = smashsoup.find('div', {'itemprop':'description'}).get_text();


    try:
        long_desc = smashsoup.find('div', {'id':'longDescription'}).get_text();
    except:

        long_desc = ""


    cats = smashsoup.find('div', {'itemprop':'genre'})

    category = ""
    for cat in cats.find_all('a'):
        category += cat.get_text() + " - "


    img = smashsoup.find('img',{'itemprop':'image'})
    source = img.get('src');
    nsource = source.replace('-thumb','')

    #compile everything into a single text document
    fo = open(filename,'a')
    fo.write(str(complete_title.encode('ascii','ignore'))+"\n\n")
    fo.write(str(short_desc.encode('ascii','ignore'))+"\n\n")
    fo.write(str(long_desc.encode('ascii','ignore'))+"\n\n")
    fo.write(category+"\n\n")

    fo.flush()
    fo.close()

    i += 1
```

Comment: First of all, your generic `except` clause will ignore all errors making it impossible to debug. I would make it more specific, only excepting one type of error.

Comment: Thank you, point noted. But I already know the code brings down all the data I want. I can write it all into a single file, just not multiple ones for some reason.

Comment: That code doesn't demonstrate your problem, does it? (you seem to be writing everything to one file). Also, please indent your code!!

Comment: I did indent my code. And each time the loop runs it should create a single file. Thats the intention. The problem is it stops creating new files about half way through the loop, which keeps on going without any error.

Comment: @DavidGallie - You haven't indented your code - just look at the first line after the `while`. Considering that early exit of the `while` is one potential explanation of your problem, indenting your example properly is important.

Comment: Any chance title and author are the same in multiple documents? You could check if a proposed filename exists and handle it.

Comment: Try with
    
    `filename = "file_{}.txt".format(i)`

and check how many files were created. If 80, than you have duplicated titles and need to handle that some way.

Comment: The thing is all the data i'm scraping from the 80 urls comes through without a problem. I can use the same loop to write to a static file and all the data will be there. The issue seems to be when generating a file just for that entry, which the code above does up to the 38th entry. Then it stops creating the files but the loop keeps going and bringing the data through as expected. And i apologize for the indentation I'm new to stack and still finding my feet.

Answer (score 0):

Big thank you to @jbet. Your comment made me go back and recheck the pages I was scraping from. Turns out there was actually a couple of identical entries on the site so obviously when I've been trying to create a separate file for each of them its been a duplicate and caused the file writing process to stop but the loop to continue. My solution was to add a timestamp to the filename before it was hashed and now all entries are created.